# Circuit breaker kicks off when one switch is on

Tags: electrical

[image]I have a ceiling fixture with three wires coming in to it one is hot, one goes to the wall switch one goes to the next room to a light switch. I need to know why would one black wire went straight to the light from the wall switch and the white wire from the wall switch went to the black hot in coming wire.

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of how this is connected? If the breaker blows then something is obviously wrong, but to determine where the short might be we need to better understand how this is connected -- whether you're looking at a switch loop, or a badly wired circuit with switch in the neutral leg, or something else entirely.

Comment: The wire at the bottom of the diagram is to the wall switch.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is known as a "*switch loop*".  A cable runs between the switch box and the fixture box, which is used to interrupt the ungrounded (hot) conductor.

Basically, power comes into the box on the black wire in the "*feed cable*".  It travels along the white wire in the "* switch cable*" to the switch, then back from the switch on the black wire in the "*switch cable*" to the fixture.